# How to find the code segment of a Linux driver in tmpfs? (in real-time)

Tags: filesystems, drivers, inode, tmpfs

I have a character driver called *drv1*, and a user application uses `ioctl` to communicate with it, which will transmit the parameter `struct file *filp`. Now I want to find out the address of the code segment of *drv1*, but I came across some problems.

At first, I guess `struct file *filp` might be useful so I looked at the definition in source code, and find a pointer `struct  inode  *f_inode; /* cached value */`. Then I roughly searched the  definition of `struct  inode` (I'm not sure whether it is right as I'm not familiar when tmpfs); a pointer named **struct address_space *i_mapping** seems to be what I need. But I don't know how to dig deeper and get stuck; there are some complicated data structures in the `struct address_space`, such as:

```
struct radix_tree_root  page_tree; /* radix tree of all pages */
```

and

```
struct rb_root  i_mmap;            /* tree of private and shared mappings */
```

Does it mean that the data of the driver *drv1* is organized as the form of `radix_tree_root`? Or does it mean that I've missed something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that for modules that are built as LKM, the memory is dynamically allocated between `MODULES_VADDR` and `MODULES_END` (see `module.c` in `arch/($YOUR_ARCH)/kernel/module.c`). I can get the start address of its function adress by using a shell command `cat /proc/kallsyms`, but no good method to do it in my code yet.

As for module that are built into the kernel image, the System.map file will give the information. Either way, I don't know how to get the address dynamically in the code.